# How to move movie files from iMovie library to Photos library

Tags: filesystem, imovie, photos.app, file-transfer, import

I have imported my movie files to the iMovie library (imovielibrary) but want them moved to the Photos library (photoslibrary).

What is the easiest most efficient way to do this without reimporting the from the original source?

Comment: Can you select them all and drag them over to the icon of the photos app, so they'll import there?

Answer (score 2):

## Find the Imovie Library

In **finder** navigate to the **Imovie Library file**. It should be in this directory `Users/NAME/Movies/iMovie Library`. Right click the  and select **Show Package Contents**.

[image]

## Find the right event

There you'll find a directory for each event. Each event directory contains a folder called original media. Those files can be dragged into Photos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "How to move movie files from iMovie library to Photos library"

Right click on the movie you want to open with Photos library and press
on "Open With" and select with "Photo library"

Answer (score -1):

Check this, i had the same problem as you and here is the solution : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1501281?tstart=0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.